# raspberry pi as gateway lan/wifi

Tags: networking, pi-4, pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os

I bought Raspberri Pi 4 and installed predefined OS on it (I am using it headless). Raspberry pi is not connected to internet.

Now I need to do this:

- in RPI Lan port is connected computer (device), IP assigned to this computer (device) should be static for this device (I think according to mac address)
- another computers will be able to login via RPi's wifi.

My goal is to be able to connect to Rpi via wifi and communicate with RPi via ssh and also with another connected devices on wifi or with that device in LAN port.

How should I set things in Rpi for this please?

Comment: Start by reading https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the snap package wifi-ap:-

https://snapcraft.io/install/wifi-ap/raspbian

After its installed its a simple matter of using the wifi-ap.config command to configure you access point and devices.

e.g. (Will give you a list of the current settings)

```
wifi-ap.config get
```

Once you've set your new options (wifi.ssid, wifi.security-passphrase and disabled=false etc.) then run..

```
wifi-ap.status restart-ap
```

You can have your PI running as a Wifi access point in minutes..

Answer (score 0):

This article will do what you want is: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

This URL setup uses a double NAT to get packets out to the Internet (Rpi-4 and router).

I've been running a Rpi-4 as an Internet firewall for my home for just over a year. I installed a second USB Ethernet dongle plugged into a 1000 mpbs USB port. I have turned off the wifi because I use Unifi accessports.  I did buy a good power supply and fan for the Rpi.

I installed "arno's" firewall and dnsmasq as a DHCP server.  I have enabled both IPv4 and IPv6.  My ISP is Comcast and I purchased an equivalent modem from Amazon.